# Apt returns: ``relocation error``

Tags: debian, apt

When running `apt-get` (or `aptitude`) I get following error

```
 apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0: symbol _ZN3URIcvNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEB5cxx11Ev version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running a mixed distribution debian installation, it's mostly `stretch` with some `buster` packages.

It turned out that I had installed mismatching versions of `libapt-pkg1.5.0` and `apt` packages. One was installed from stretch other from buster, since these packages contain interdependent `*so` libraries, it causes linkage error.

Solution is to install both of these packages from single distribution, in my case I installed following:

- https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/libapt-pkg5.0/download
- https://packages.debian.org/stretch/apt

The above worked as a temporary solution, as `apt` was complaining about system being in broken state (some buster package required never `libapt-pkg*`). In the end I upgraded both packages to use `buster` versions, and everything works like charm (you might want to pin these packages to `stretch` version if you want/need it).

Comment: maybe using some apt-pinning will be useful. +1 both for the question and answer.